# MSKLC : How to tell Windows about the first row of my custom keyboard layout

Tags: custom-keyboard, msklc

In Windows, one can install a custom keyboard layout, made with MSKLC.

However, when using the `Language and Keyboard Options` dialog, the "moniker" that consists in the sequence of characters found on the first row of the layout, is not displayed for a custom layout.

[image]

How do I tell Windows that my custom keyboard layout is an "AZERTY" variant?

I have used various tools to find out where this information is stored and it does not appear to be in the layout DLL itself. I also search in the registry but could not seem to find what I was looking for.

Comment: See answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64802169/613130

Comment: This question is very off-topic, and would be more likely to get an answer on Super User.

Comment: @xanatos the answer you are referring two is under one of my other questions about custom layouts but is not related.