# MSKLC : How to associate a country to a custom keyboard layout

Tags: custom-keyboard, msklc

I made a custom keyboard layout with MSKLC.
I thought I followed the instructions carefully and [chose appropriate values](https://github.com/springcomp/optimized-azerty-win/blob/master/KBFRZ71.klc#L7-L9) for the `LOCALENAME` and `LOCALID` parameters.

However, in the switch-keyboard popup that is displayed by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or on the TaskBar, the country associated with my custom layout is not displayed.

[image]

How to I author my layout so that Windows knows about the country it should be associated with?

Comment: Hi! Were you able to solve this problem? Interested because I'm experimenting with an "extended" italian keyboard

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet . The current answer seems to suggest hijacking the existing builtin layout and injecting my DLL instead. But I would rather do the correct thing. I’ve long suspected Windows has internal knowledge about this mapping deep somewhere and that might not be exposed to authors of custom layouts.

Answer (score 2):

From some experiments I've done with a custom keyboard of mine, you have to change the registry.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layouts\0000040c
```

change

```
"Layout File"="KBDFR.dll"
```

to

```
"Layout File"="YourDll.dll"
```

and then set the

```
"Layout Display Name"="@%SystemRoot%\system32\YourDll.dll,-1000"
```

Now if you reboot you should see both the keyboard type and the correct first row. As an added bonus, the Remote Desktop won't default to english keyboard, and it will simply use the "basic" French keyboard.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. Are you suggesting I change the original FRA layout with my custom layout DLL? What about if I want to have both registered and would like to switch between the two at any time?

Comment: @MaximeLabelle That I is the only solution I was able to find... And so you can't have two FR layouts. In truth my problem was more that when I used Remote Desktop to a different computer, my layout wasn't recognized as ITA, and so I had on the remote PC the ENG layout...

Answer (score 0):

These short abbreviated **keyboard layout names** seems to be sawn inside Windows language bar source code. Only layouts that are supplied with Windows have them.

Abbreviated **language names** seems sawn too. If I requesting [LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-siso-constants) of `LOCALENAME` and then uppercasing it - it still resulting in lating string. `RUS` for exampe, not `РУС` for Russian.

Some asian IMEs are drawn as images on this bar.

PS: In Windows XP they had just used [LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-sabbrev-constants) - see `InatCreateIconBySize` in `NT/windows/advcore/ctf/uim/internat.cpp` in leaked Windows source code. :)

[image: layouts][image]

Comment: Yes, that’s my conclusion too. So in effect, what I want to do is impossible.

Comment: Well, that is unfortunate as I too have been wanting to do make those layout codes appear properly. Thanks for looking up the source code though. ;) Seriously though, Microsoft should put more effort into making Windows properly configurable instead of reinventing the visual design and changing where the start menu is located every few years...

Comment: Actually for old pre-Metro-style language selection bar there was ability to change icon for keyboard layout: https://littlemissgoth.livejournal.com/110637.html But that seems not working anymore for Windows 10.